# How to use custom icon for react-datepicker component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, datepicker

I'm using [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) and would like to open the calendar from separate calendar button and still show the user choice in field next to that button.

However, documentation doesn't show any example how to open the calendar from custom button. How could I achieve this custom functionality?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to toogle down some element you can just use Java Script:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").slideToggle();
});
```

I suggest you to don't rely on scripts written by someone else, becouse you could not understand them and all your work will be in a mess. Read Java Script tutorial to work by your own ;)

[Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)